# ghci configuration - haskell - Error while changing ~/.ghci file

Tags: haskell, ubuntu, ghc, ghci

I was trying to pu my GHCi pretty using this: http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/144biy/pretty_output_in_ghci_howto_in_comments/

But while runnig GHCi this error appear and I cannot apply the colour changes.

```
user@pcname:~$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.

<no location info>:
    Could not find module `IPPrint'
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.

<no location info>:
    Could not find module `Language.Haskell.HsColour'
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.

<no location info>:
    Could not find module `Language.Haskell.HsColour.Colourise'
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.

<no location info>:
    Could not find module `Language.Haskell.HsColour.Output'
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.

<interactive>:7:21:
    Failed to load interface for `HsColour'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

<interactive>:9:26:
    Failed to load interface for `HsColour'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

Top level: Not in scope: `myPrint'

Top level: Not in scope: `myPrint'

<interactive>:19:26:
    Failed to load interface for `HsColour'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

What do you suggest?

I'm currently using Ubuntu 14.04 and GHCi 7.6.3

Comment: Have you installed the required dependencies?  It looks very much like you don't have [`hscolour`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hscolour) installed system-wide

Comment: that's my problem I don't know how to install them

Comment: i've already done "sudo aptitude install hscolour", but it does not seems to be working after the installation

Comment: I would recommend install packages using `cabal` when possible.  If you don't have it installed, search for it in aptitude, it might be named `cabal-install` or something similar.  The `cabal` tool has a lot of other features as well, such as for creating and managing your own projects.  From the instructions in the reddit post, you'll need the `IPPrint` and `HsColour` packages installed with `cabal install IPPrint` and `cabal install HsColour`.  If those install successfully, then you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: almost there but now `cabal`  gives me this error `cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
Extra-1.46.1 depends on bzlib-0.5.0.4 which failed to install.
bzlib-0.5.0.4 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
ipprint-0.5 depends on bzlib-0.5.0.4 which failed to install.
`

Comment: just fixed it using `sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev`
but now I have no colours on my ghci... (but no errors)

Comment: this is the error: `Top level: Not in scope: `myPrint'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarising the comments: you need to install the Haskell modules `hscolour` and `ipprint`. For the second, you need to have the `libbz2-dev` package installed. So:

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
cabal update
cabal install ipprint hscolour
```